# Return Enumerator without using existing iterators

Tags: ruby, arrays, iterator, wrapper, enumerator

How do I return Enumerator from my array wrapper without using already existing array iterators?

```
class MyArray

  def initialize
   @inner = []
  end

  def each
    index = 0
    while index < @inner.size
      yield @inner[index] if block_given?
      index += 1
    end
  end
end
```

I can't figure out how to avoid calling things like `@inner.each` at the end of the `each` method.

Comment: @sawa I fixed it. There was a naming mismatch.

Comment: @sawa Ok, there was an extra `def` before `class`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

```
@inner = [1, 2, 3]
```

Code

```
@inner.to_enum
```

will return an enumerator.

```
enum = @inner.to_enum
enum.each{|e| p e}
# => 1, 2, 3
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution, code correction and english correction :)